# Maria db using Airflow MySqlHook to connect, the query takes forever and times out

Tags: mariadb, airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm running the below query in MariaDB using the Airflow MySQLHook.
The table has 5 millions rows and 15 columns and it timeout after running for 2 hours!

Error message:

> (2013, 'Lost connection to server during query') unable to rollback;
> 1009)

I need to get all rows based on the modified_date which is a timestamp, I initially tried this:

```
select * from comment_table where DATE(modified_date) = '2023-06-01';
```

I then tried to chunk it out by getting the the modified_date based on 6 hour timestamp interval and it still times out and still runs for 2 hours!

```
SELECT * FROM comment_table WHERE modified_date between str_to_date('2023-06-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND  str_to_date('2023-06-01 06:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

This is what the entire code looks like:

```
hook = MySqlHook("mariadb_conn_id")

with hook.get_conn().cursor() as cursor:

     query = 'select * from comment_table.....'
     df_results = pd.read_sql(query, hook.get_conn())
```

Comment: Any keys involved? Can you supply an EXPLAIN in your question? You certainly don't want  to use DATE() in your WHERE. I think that will force it to scan the entire table, ignoring keys.  You also don't need to use str_to_date() conversion, just supply the two strings.

Comment: @UncleCarl - thanks for responding! What do you mean by 'supply an EXPLAIN'? and how can I better the query without using DATE() or  str_to_date() ? i thought those were the only ways to get this type of filtering on a timestamp?

Comment: You haven't given enough information for someone to give a complete answer. The EXPLAIN will tell us more about the query. I'm not familiar with Airflow, but you would just put "EXPLAIN" before your SELECT and MySQL will tell about the query. Knowing the create table definition would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by adding an index to the `modified_date` column, I just forgot... And @UncleCarl 's suggestion about doing an EXPLAIN before the query also let me see that the index was added after it was created.